# php mysql multiple where codition

Tags: php

```
$customer_phonenumber = $_POST['customer_phonenumber'];
$customer_firstname = $_POST['customer_firstname'];


$sql =mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer WHERE customer_firstname = '$customer_firstname' OR customer_phonenumber = '$customer_phonenumber' ") or die(mysql_error());



$sqlarray=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

output :- it will show correct output if and only if both the first name and phone number is provided else it will show some random value.

Comment: Then use `AND` instead of `OR` if you want both of them to be true. Also try implement some security to your code.

Comment: Check if they are set before checking for them in the query. Switch to using `mysqli` functions as `mysql` functions are deprecated. And for the love of your server, don't use `$_POST` variables in a database query without escaping them first, you're just asking for an injection attack.

Comment: Can you formulate your question to be an actual one?

Comment: thanks GeoffAtkinsif & if i use mysql_real_escape_string it will solve the purpose and i am new to php.
i started lessons for pdo soon i will change all to pdo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some customers without first name or phone set, and corresponding form values are also empty, then you'll get incorrect response. You should check your form data:

```
$filter = array();
if (!empty($_POST['customer_phonenumber'])) {
    $filter[] = 'customer_phonenumber = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customer_phonenumber']).'"';
}
if (!empty($_POST['customer_firstname'])) {
    $filter[] = 'customer_firstname = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customer_firstname']).'"';
}

if (count($filter)) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_customer WHERE ".implode(' OR ', $filter)) or die(mysql_error());

    $sqlarray = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
} else {
    echo 'No data';
}
```